# Python CFFI - Unable to use formatted Python string as byte-array in function call

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

I'm learning various ways of how to include code written in `C` to `Python` because I have an API for a Microchip device which is pretty...tedious to work with and I would like to make my life easier in the future by adding a `Python` wrapper for it which will allow me to test stuff much faster. One way of doing that is to use the `cffi` module which even provides its user with `verify()` that basically calls the `C` compiler to check if the provided `cdef(...)` is correct.

I've written a small project so that I can first learn how to properly used `cffi`. It consists of two parts

1. **Library** - written in C. I use `cmake` and `make` accordingly to compile its code:

   **`CMakeLists.txt`**

   ```
   project(testlib_for_cffi)
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

   set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
   # Debug build
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -g -O0")
   # Release build
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Os")

   aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
   add_library(testcffi SHARED ${SRC_LIST})

   # Not required for the library but needed if I want to check for memory leaks with Valgrind
   set(SRC main.c)
   add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC testcffi)
   ```

   **`testcffi.h`**

   ```
   typedef struct
   {
     double x;
     double y;
     double z;
     char *label;
   } point_t;

   // Creation, printing and deletion
   point_t* createPoint(double x, double y, double z, char *label);
   void printPoint(point_t *point);
   void deletePoint(point_t *point);
   ```

   **`testcffi.c`**

   ```
   #include "testcffi.h"
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <malloc.h>

   point_t* createPoint(double x, double y, double z, char *label) {
     point_t *p = malloc(sizeof(point_t));
     p->x = x;
     p->y = y;
     p->z = z;
     p->label = label;

     return p;
   }

   void printPoint(point_t *point) {
     if(point == NULL) return;
     printf("Data:\n\tx : %f\n\ty : %f\n\tz : %f\n\tmsg : \"%s\"\n", point->x, point->y, point->z, point->label);
   }

   void deletePoint(point_t *point) {
     if(point == NULL) return;
     free(point);
     point = NULL;
   }
   ```
2. **Test code in Python** - the code demonstrates the usage of the `struct` along with the three functions from the library above:

   ```
           #!/usr/bin/python3

           from cffi import FFI
           import random

           ffi = FFI()

           # Add library's header
           ffi.cdef('''
               typedef struct
               {
                 double x;
                 double y;
                 double z;
                 char * label;
               } point_t;

               // Creation, printing and deletion
               point_t * createPoint(double x=0., double y=0., double z=0., char *label="my_label");
               void printPoint(point_t *point);
               void deletePoint(point_t *point);
           ''')

           # Load shared object from subdirectory `build`
           CLibTC = ffi.dlopen('build/libtestcffi.so')

           def createList(length=5):
               if len:
                   lst = []
                   for i in range(0, length):
                       lst.append(CLibTC.createPoint(
                           float(random.random()*(i+1)*10),
                           float(random.random()*(i+1)*10),
                           float(random.random()*(i+1)*10),
                           b'hello'  # FIXME Why does ONLY this work?
                           # ('point_%d' % i).encode('utf-8') # NOT WORKING
                           # 'point_{0}'.format(str(i)).encode('utf-8') # NOT WORKING
                           # ffi.new('char[]', 'point_{0}'.format(str(i)).encode('utf-8')) # NOT WORKING
                       ))

                   return lst
               return None


           def printList(lst):
               if lst and len(lst):
                   for l in lst:
                       CLibTC.printPoint(l)

           list_of_dstruct_ptr = createList(10)
           printList(list_of_dstruct_ptr)
   ```

The problem comes from the byte-array that I have to convert my `Python` string to in order to pass the data to the respective location in my `C` code.

The code above is working however I would like to use other then strings similar to `b'hello'`. That is why I tried to use the `format()` (along with its short-form `%`) in `Python` to combine a bunch of letters and a number but. It didn't work out. I either get `""` as a value for the `label` parameter of my `point_t` `struct` or I get a weird alternating garbage data (mostly weird characters that are neither letters nor digits).

I thought that I'm using the `encode()` function incorrectly however when I tested it inside my `Python` interactive shell I got the SAME output as using `b'...'`.

Any idea what's going on here?

---

**A nice-to-know question:** From what I've read so far it seems that `cffi` uses the garbage-collection in `Python` to deallocated the dynamically allocated memory in your C code. I've tested it with a bunch of points but I would like to make sure this is actually always the case.

---

**Update:**
Okay, so it seems that things without `new(...)` do work however in that case all the values are the same as the last one in the loop. For example if the loop goes up to 10, then all `struct` Python objects will have the 10 in their labels. This seems to be a reference issue. When I use `new(...)` I get garbage data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C code, the `point_t` structure holds in `label` a `char *`, i.e. a pointer to some other place in memory.  If you create 10 `point_t` structures, they hold pointers to 10 strings that are somewhere else in memory.  You have to make sure that these 10 strings are kept alive for as long as you use the `point_t` structures.  CFFI cannot guess that there is such a relationship.  When you do the call `CLibTC.createPoint(..., some_string)`, CFFI allocates a `char[]` array around the call and copies `some_string` in it, but this `char[]` memory is freed after the call.

Use that kind of code instead:

```
c_string = ffi.new("char[]", some_string)
lst.append(createPoint(..., c_string))
keepalive.append(c_string)
```

where `keepalive` is another list, which you must make sure remains alive for as long as you need the `point_t` to contain valid `label`'s.

Comment: :O Totally right and I totally missed that even though I read it like 1000 times in the docs. LOL So basically when creating a wrapper of a C-based API one has to create special objects which will allow better management of such references. Thank you so much. I got some white hairs growing here during my struggle to solve this.